# SQL LEFT OUTER JOIN Query, need to add a WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql

I have this query here:

```
SELECT 
    Q.Question_ID, 
    Q.Question, 
    Q.Department, 
    CASE WHEN C.selected = 'true' THEN CAST('true' AS BIT) ELSE CAST('false' AS BIT) END AS Selected 
FROM TPM_Questions_Default AS Q 
LEFT OUTER JOIN customerQuestions AS C 
    ON Q.Question_ID = C.QuestionID 
   AND C.CustomerID = 123456
```

This returns all items in TPM_Questions_Default and if a QuestionID does not exist in the customerQuestions the bools are false automatically

Now I need to reuse this query else where but I need to add in another WHERE CLAUSE (`AND Q.Question_ID = 2`) which needs to return one row.

When I add it to the end of the query it still returns all items in TPM_Questions_Default, I just need it to return one. How can I adjust this query to do what I want?

Comment: can you not add the condition to the `join` clause?

Comment: Are you adding a `WHERE` clause or adding it to your `JOIN` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are adding it to your JOIN clause:

```
SELECT 
    Q.Question_ID, 
    Q.Question, 
    Q.Department, 
    CASE WHEN C.selected = 'true' THEN CAST('true' AS BIT) ELSE CAST('false' AS BIT) END AS Selected 
FROM TPM_Questions_Default AS Q 
LEFT OUTER JOIN customerQuestions AS C 
    ON Q.Question_ID = C.QuestionID 
   AND C.CustomerID = 123456
   AND Q.Question_ID = 2
```

When you should be adding it as a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 
    Q.Question_ID, 
    Q.Question, 
    Q.Department, 
    CASE WHEN C.selected = 'true' THEN CAST('true' AS BIT) ELSE CAST('false' AS BIT) END AS Selected 
FROM TPM_Questions_Default AS Q 
LEFT OUTER JOIN customerQuestions AS C 
    ON Q.Question_ID = C.QuestionID 
   AND C.CustomerID = 123456
WHERE Q.Question_ID = 2
```